# 'Couldn't resolve host 'metadata' while accessing ML model from local

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-sdk

I have issues accessing the ML model on google cloud. While running the command

gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=$MODEL_BINARIES --json-instances=examples.json

I see the following issue.

2018-04-06 12:20:36.276951: I tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/retrying_utils.cc:77] The operation failed and will be automatically retried in 1.06067 seconds (attempt 1 out of 10), caused by: Unavailable: Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 0, error code 6, error message 'Couldn't resolve host 'metadata'')
2018-04-06 12:20:37.385676: I tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/retrying_utils.cc:77] The operation failed and will be automatically retried in 1.12525 seconds (attempt 2 out of 10), caused by: Unavailable: Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 0, error code 6, error message 'Couldn't resolve host 'metadata'')
2018-04-06 12:20:38.559673: I tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/retrying_utils.cc:77] The operation failed and will be automatically retried in 2.86851 seconds (attempt 3 out of 10), caused by: Unavailable: Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 0, error code 6, error message 'Couldn't resolve host 'metadata'')

I used the command to authenticate 'gcloud auth application-default login' but i still have the issue. The credential using which I authenticated have owner permission to project. Also, I noticed there is no issue accessing the data from BigQuery tables but there is issue while accessing Model.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? Can you edit your post and add a bit more information about your use case? What steps did you follow until you reached the point where you are getting this error?

Comment: Hi @VictorGGl, we still have the issue. We figured that whenever we are accessing model binaries on cloud, we end up getting this issue. We have same error when we run TensorBoard. So, I cleaned up the Google cloud sdk, reinstalled it, reconfigured with user account using 'gcloud init' and then authenticated using 'gcloud auth application-default login', which didn't help. 

As I'm accessing/calling model from a server, I then created a service account, saved the 'key.json' file and 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' in bash is mapped to 'key.json' and sourced it. This didn't help either.

Comment: Can you add more information about the Versions you are using (in Tensorflow and Python)?

Comment: Python version 2.7.5 and tensorflow version 1.4.0

Comment: Can you raise an issue in the Public Issue Tracker adding your project number and offering as much information as possible?: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187220

Comment: @VictorGGl I also face the same error when trying `tensorboard --logdir='gs://...'`. I submitted [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110372774) on the link you provided